# Styling a option element in Firefox

Tags: html, html-select

it's looks like this bug are available again in new version FF (51.0.1):
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=79107

[image]

Can anyone suggest workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

It's looks like not working with JS also:

```
var sel = document.getElementById("colorSelect");

sel.onfocus = function() {
    var nodes = this.options;
    for (i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        nodes[i].style.color = nodes[i].style.color;
    }
};
```

http://output.jsbin.com/felisubare/1